# Is there a way of including HTML pages without needing any javascript or server-side code, only HTML

Tags: html, include, server-side-includes

Is there a way of including HTML pages without needing any javascript or server-side code, only HTML.

Basically I can't be sure if the server supports server side includes. I don't want to use javascript and I don't want to use any PHP or other server side functionality.

Is there any way to do this. At the moment I suspect not, but would be very interested if it were possible.

Answer (score 8):

Use some [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/frames.html) in your page

> HTML frames allow authors to present
>   documents in multiple views, which may
>   be independent windows or subwindows.

`<iframe></iframe>` is the tag you need to include inline floating frames.

*Quick tip with iframes:* Be sure you open and close the tag explicitly, if not some browsers will complain

Answer (score 2):

You can use [framesets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(World_Wide_Web)).

Answer (score 1):

[HTML imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/), part of [HTML Components](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/explainer/), aims to do exactly this.

[HTML5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) offers a great tutorial to get started with HTML imports.

According to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports), only Chrome is supporting HTML imports today.